# Sec-WebSocket-Protcol is not working with react native

Tags: react-native, websocket

I'm trying to establish WebSocket connection with server using WebSocket library. Server requires Sec-WebSocket-Protocol : "sip" as request headers for authentication. I added it in WebSocket using `new WebSocket("wss://abc.xyz:7443", "sip")` but it's not working. I'm not getting that header in reqest at server side. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue of TLS version suppport on client and server side. Server was not supporting TLS v1.2 and React Native support TLS v1.2, so it was creating an issue.